# R match/compare two matrix in R but loop seems doesn't work well

Tags: r

```r
N = 4
comN <- gtools::permutations(2, N, v = c(0, 1), repeats = TRUE)
comstate <- matrix (NA, N, N)
for (i in 1:2^N) {
  for (j in 1:N) {
    comstate[1:N, ] = comN[i, ] # spoint<-comN[i,]
    tcomstate = t(comstate)     # need transpose "comstate" to ensure col stands for the component state
    tcomstate[j, j] = (1 - comN[i, j])
    y <- which(colSums(t(comN) == tcomstate[j, ]) == ncol(comN))
  }
}
y
```

I tried to get y manually, （i=3）comN[3,], it works well, y=1,4,7,15 but when I go back to the loop, it is only 15, it need to be four values 1,4,7,15

Comment: I don't really know R, but aren't you keeping only one value of y of the for i loop, as you overwrite it each time? Don't you need a list or an array as in other languages?

Comment: Instead of asking to debug your code, maybe write a short a description of what we are trying to achieve, input data, expected output.

Comment: @B. Go is right, y needs to be a list. You can create a list with ```y <- list()``` then add values to the list with ```y[[i]] <- which(colSums(t(comN) == tcomstate[j, ]) == ncol(comN))```

Comment: thanks, but it seems still one value, instead of four value, no matter array or list. for array:   y<-array()
+   y[[i]]<- which(colSums(t(comN)==tcomstate[j,])==ncol(comN))}
> y
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA  4  for list: +   y<-list()
+   y[[i]]<- which(colSums(t(comN)==tcomstate[j,])==ncol(comN))}
> y
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
NULL

[[5]]
NULL

[[6]]
NULL

[[7]]
NULL

[[8]]
NULL

[[9]]
NULL

[[10]]
NULL

[[11]]
NULL

[[12]]
NULL

[[13]]
NULL

[[14]]
NULL

[[15]]
NULL

[[16]]
[1] 4

Comment: I think you are right, I overwrite the y value, but how to solve it?